# Can't verify CSRF token authenticity when using prepend_before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following application controller.  I recently added the set_customer which I want to execute before the authorize part.  The **prepend_before_action** does that perfectly.  However as soon as I add that line I'm getting this error: **Can't verify CSRF token authenticity**

The current_user isn't nil, so when I debug it goes right over the set_customer part and straight into the authorize method.  When I remove the **prepend_before_action** line it works again.  How can I fix this (while keeping the CSRF protection of course.

Maybe important to mention: I'm also using devise.  The error comes on   **Devise::SessionsController#create**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception, prepend: true
  before_action :authorize
  prepend_before_action :authorize, :set_customer

  def authorize
    if current_permission.allow?(params[:controller], params[:action], current_resource)
      current_permission.permit_params! params
    else
      raise Permission::NotAuthorized
    end
  end

  def set_customer
    if current_user.nil?
      # some unimportant code since current_user isn't nil
    end
  end
```

Comment: Have you tried moving `protect_from_forgery` below `prepend_before_action`? One of the suggestions on the Devise GitHub for the CSRF error is to change the order you call them, or add prepend to the p_f_p. To my understanding, `prepend` sets the thing being prepended to index 0. That would be putting your `authorize` call before your p_f_p call in execution. Just a thought.

Comment: @josh that worked!  Thx, if you add it here as answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried moving `protect_from_forgery` below `prepend_before_action`? One of the suggestions on the Devise GitHub for the CSRF error is to change the order you call them, or add prepend to the p_f_p. To my understanding, prepend sets the thing being prepended to index 0. That would be putting your authorize call before your p_f_p call in execution.